# Why does set null to integer variable throw Exception

Tags: java, casting

I try to initial Integer variable with short if syntax
But get an exception in run time.

```
"Cannot cast numeric value to 'null'"
```

This is my code:

```
  Integer key= (resultLine[index] == null) ? null : ((Byte)resultLine[index]).intValue();
```

and if I change it to:

```
  Integer key= (resultLine[index] == null) ? 1 : ((Byte)resultLine[index]).intValue();
```

It works correctly.

Any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: Because both arms of a conditional statements must return the same type.

Comment: Can't find the duplicate right now, but as mentioned the second arm is currently an `int` (not a nullable type). `Integer key = (resultLine[index] == null) ? null : Integer.valueOf((byte) resultLine[index]);` (avoid casting to a `Byte` like that).

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know it before.

Comment: @Batty Is that the _exact_ error you are getting? [I'm having a hard time reproducing that error](https://ideone.com/AbmzD5). (And [the only match I can find on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Cannot+cast+numeric+value+to+%27null%27%22) is this very question.)